# Java using ValueAnimator with BigInteger?

Tags: java, android, biginteger

I'm trying to animate between two values using `BigInteger` instead of `int` like I was using before. So far I have not found a way to do this, is it possible?

```
final ValueAnimator amountAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofInt(initialValue, finalValue);
```

Of course, `BigInteger` is not accepted there...
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use any type in ValueAnimator, as long as You provide your own [TypeEvaluator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/TypeEvaluator.html) (somehow pseudocode example):

```
public class BigIntegerEvaluator implements TypeEvaluator<BigInteger>{
    @Override
    public BigInteger evaluate(float v, BigInteger start, BigInteger end) {
        //todo: implement this
        return start + v * (end - start);
    }
}
```

Then provide it into general valueAnimator:

```
final ValueAnimator amountAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new BigIntegerEvaluator(), initialValue, finalValue);
```

But I'm not sure about animating on type `BigInteger` itself since Evaluator is called on each frame with new fraction, are you sure `long` type is not enough for your use case?

Comment: Possible implementation (assumes 'v' is a proportion - would have to check for v==0 and return start): start.add((end.subtract(start).divide(new BigInteger(Integer.toString((int)(1F/v))))));